# Thread safety in std::map of std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, dictionary, shared-ptr

I know there are a lot of similar questions with answers around, but since I still don't understand this particular case, I decided to pose a question.

What I have is a map of shared_ptrs to a dynamically allocated array (MyVector). What I want is limited concurrent access without the need to lock. I know that the map per se is not thread safe, but I always thought what I'm doing here should be ok, which is:

I fill the map in a single threaded environment like that:

```
typedef shared_ptr<MyVector<float>> MyVectorPtr;

for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
{
    content[i] = MyVectorPtr(new MyVector<float>(numRows));
}
```

After the initialization, I have one thread that reads from the elements and one that replaces what the shared_ptrs point to.

Thread 1:

```
for(auto i=content.begin();i!=content.end();i++)
{
    MyVectorPtr p(i->second);
    if (p)
    {
        memory_use+=sizeof(int) + sizeof(float) * p->number;
    }
}
```

Thread 2:

```
    for (auto itr=content.begin();content.end()!=itr;++itr)
    {
        itr->second.reset(new MyVector<float>(numRows));
    }
```

After a while I get either a seg fault or a double free in one of the two threads. Somehow not really surprisingly, but still I don't really get it.

The reasons why I thought this would work, are:

1. I don't add or remove any items of the map in the multi-threaded
   environment, so the iterators should always point to something valid.
2. I thought concurrently changing a single element of the map is fine as long as the operation is atomic.
3. I thought the operations I do on the shared_ptr (increment ref count, decrement ref count in Thread 1, reset in Thread 2) are atomic. [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127816/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety-explained)

Obviously, either one ore more of my assumptions are wrong, or I'm not doing what I think I am. I think that reset actually is not thread safe, would std::atomic_exchange help?

Can someone release me? Thanks a lot!

If someone wants to try out, here is the full code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>


using namespace std;

template<class T>
class MyVector
{
public:
    MyVector(int length)
    : number(length)
    , array(new T[length])
    {
    }

    ~MyVector()
    {
        if (array != NULL)
        {
            delete[] array;
        }
        array = NULL;
    }

    int number;

private:
    T* array;
};

typedef shared_ptr<MyVector<float>> MyVectorPtr;


static map<int,MyVectorPtr> content;
const int numRows = 1000;
const int numElements = 10;

//pthread_mutex_t write_lock;

double get_cache_size_in_megabyte()
{
    double memory_use=0;
    //BlockingLockGuard guard(write_lock);
    for(auto i=content.begin();i!=content.end();i++)
    {
        MyVectorPtr p(i->second);
        if (p)
        {
            memory_use+=sizeof(int) + sizeof(float) * p->number;
        }
    }

    return memory_use/(1024.0*1024.0);

}


void* write_content(void*)
{
    while(true)
    {
        //BlockingLockGuard guard(write_lock);
        for (auto itr=content.begin();content.end()!=itr;++itr)
        {
            itr->second.reset(new MyVector<float>(numRows));
            cout << "one new written" <<endl;
        }

    }
    return NULL;
}

void* loop_size_checker(void*)
{
    while (true)
    {
        cout << get_cache_size_in_megabyte() << endl;;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        content[i] = MyVectorPtr(new MyVector<float>(numRows));
    }

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr) ;
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);

    pthread_t *grid_proc3 = new pthread_t;
    pthread_create(grid_proc3, &attr, &loop_size_checker,NULL);

    pthread_t *grid_proc = new pthread_t;
    pthread_create(grid_proc, &attr, &write_content,(void*)NULL);


    // to keep alive and avoid content being deleted
    sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Rule of 3/5/0 for `MyVector`... (and why not use `std::vector` ?)

Comment: `if (array != NULL)` -- There is no need to check for NULL when issuing a call to `delete[]`.

Comment: `shared_ptr::operator=(const shared_ptr &other)` Is not thread safe if `other` is being assigned in another thread. `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<X>>` is probably not lock less, so I guess if you want to stay lock less you need to managed the memory yourself.

Comment: You're right about the MyVector, this is a dummy class which I used to represent the problem I have in the productive code. I will edit the example, but still, adding a copy constr. etc. doesn't help in the main problem.

Comment: Actually, I think writing an atomic `shared_ptr::operator=(const shared_ptr &other)` is impossible, since you can increment the reference count only if you know the object is alive. Reading `other` will be meaningless since until you get to actually do something with it, it might have been freed. Without transnational memory you cannot atomically read one memory location and modify another. On x86 it is possible only using TSX.

Comment: You could use a doubly linked smart pointer for this (something like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/smarttests.htm).

Comment: @Dani, Thx, that probably is the root of the evil. Couldn't that atomic_compare_exchange_weak with a loop work without locking?

Comment: @schluchc: You need to modify the value of the refcount (location `A`) relying on the `other.pointer` value (location `B`). `atomic_compare_exchange*` modifies a location based on its value alone (location `A` based on the value of location `A`)

Comment: @Dani: I see, hmm, sounds like I really don't get around the lock then. If I understand right (it's late here) then it's a conceptual problem and also an other implementation, as proposed below, cannot help around the lock.

Comment: I think the following will work: implement a shared pointer that stores the pointer attached to a copy count. Copying the pointer outside would be using atomic compare exchange of (pointer, copy count) to (pointer, copy count + 1). Assigning to the pointer will be atomic exchange (no compare) of (old, old copy count) with (new, 0) and then atomically adding the old copy count to the reference count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117139/discussion-between-schluchc-and-dani).

Answer (score 2):

> I thought concurrently changing a single element of the map is fine as long as the operation is atomic.

Changing the element in a map is not atomic unless you have a atomic type like `std::atomic`.

> I thought the operations I do on the shared_ptr (increment ref count, decrement ref count in Thread 1, reset in Thread 2) are atomic.

That is correct.  Unfortunately you are also changing the underlying pointer.  That pointer is not atomic.  Since it is not atomic you need synchronization.

One thing you can do though is use the [atomic free functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) that are introduced with `std::shared_ptr`.  This will let you avoid having to use a `mutex`.

Comment: how can you call reset on a shared_ptr without changing the underlying pointer?

Comment: The atomic functions I looked into, but according to @Dani they don't really solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;**

Changing `std::map` isn't thread safe, while using `std::shared_ptr` regarding additional references is.

You should protect accessing your map regarding read/write operations using an appropriate synchronization mechanism, like e.g. a `std::mutex`.

Also if the state of an instance referenced by the `std::shared_ptr` should change, it needs to be protected against data races if it's accessed from concurrent threads.

---

BTW, the `MyVector` you are showing is a way too naive implementation.

Comment: If I'm right, I don't change the map, but only the std::shared_ptr in the map, so why does that not work?

Comment: I know that a lock would solve the problem, but if not absolutely necessary, I want to do it lock free.

Answer (score 0):

Lets expand `MyVectorPtr p(i->second);` which is running on thread-1:

The constructor called for this is:

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) = default;
```

Which probably boils down to 2 assignments of the `underlying shared pointer` and the `reference count`.

It may very well happen that thread 2 would delete the shared pointer while in thread-1 the pointer is being assigned to `p`. The underlying pointer stored inside `shared_ptr` is *not* atomic.

Thus, you usage of `std::shared_ptr` is not thread safe. It is thread safe as long as you do not update or modify the underlying pointer.