# How shared_ptr copy constructor work?

Tags: c++

I was thinking, if the main thread is deleting a shared_ptr, and cause reference count drop to 0, and in the process of deleting the referenced pointer heap memory, and at the same time, another thread is copying a shared_ptr reference (inside the copy constructor already). What would happen then?

Comment: hey thanks for the -1 and not leaving any comment

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but if I had to guess, it was probably done because your question is a single run on sentence which is barely readable and doesn't provide any example of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127816/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety-explained ?

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe isn't allowed to happen in standard compliant code. In case it does appear in code, you have undefined behavior.

The `std::shared_ptr` class isn't thread safe. You aren't allowed to access the same instance from 2 threads without synchronization, as that is a race condition.

So, when the counter is read, if it isn't zero, it is incremented and some pointers are copied over.

Comment: What do you mean by shared_ptr class is not thread safe? i believe they do have atomic or lock inside the implementation right?

Comment: You can use multiple instances in multiple threads, you can't use the same instance in multiple threads

Comment: what if i do:
std::thread([&](){ //reference to the shared_ptr })

Comment: Use [=]{} instead

Comment: yea, just replying your last statement

Comment: Let me rephrase in the original answer: impossible -> not valid code

Comment: I am wondering what my example would happen if we really doing referencing of shared_ptr

Comment: Ok lets me try out an example

Comment: std::shared_ptr<int> a = std::make_shared<int>(10);
    
    std::thread([&](){
        
        std::shared_ptr<int> b(a);
        
        });

Comment: the above code compile. not sure what you mean not valid code.

Comment: Using a nullptr or deleted instance also compiles

Comment: I dont think you get the point here that you CAN reference the shared_ptr, and from my answer, it would cause the problem potentially (as the answer explained).

Comment: @Bryan Fok Just because something *compiles* does *not* mean that the code is valid. Syntactically valid, yes. But not necessarily free of Undefined Behaviour, implementation defined behaviour, use of languagee extensions, non-portable constructs, logic errors, race conditions, etc etc.

Comment: His original answer was simpler, the code was just showing it is valid syntax Jesper, and it is not the question I was asking anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog did answer my question? I am not sure. So if the shared_ptr is copy to the thread, there are no chance that the problem I mention would happen.

> shared_ptr must have at least 2 pointers, so it’s bigger than a raw pointer. It also guarantees thread-safety for all methods as long as each thread has its own copy.

Comment: I think it is very interesting, and it changed the way I always thought about shared_ptr until I try to implement a simple version of it for fun. I think the blog, and the response from Lothar at the below link did answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127816/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety-explained