# Can returning a shared const pointer in multithreaded function cause timing problems

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

example:

```
std::shared_ptr<config const> ClassA::getConfig() {
  folly::SharedMutex::ReadHolder rh(rwConfigLock_);
  return config_;
}
```

The return is in the lock. However, does the shared pointer get copied over before the lock is released? I am afraid of a situation where the shared_pointers counter would get written to by different threads at the same time.

Comment: Yes, it's copied before the lock is released. But why do you need a lock here? `shared_pointer` is designed to be used in a multithreaded context so I think you can omit the lock : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr.

Comment: the counter manipulation is always thred safe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127816/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety-explained

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is thread-safe in this regard.

Comment: No need for a lock here.

Comment: Didn't realize shared_ptrs had thread safety baked in already! thanks!

Comment: With your intended design, the user wouldn't have the right to copy the result? It would suck!

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` itself is thread safe by design. So **the code is safe** with respect to returning the `shared_ptr` instance.

---

More precisely: **it is required to copy `config_`** to be thread safe. And even **the lock is not dispensable**.

Assuming that your lock prevents `config_` from being modified while the function executes, the *copy* of `config_` is done while the lock is held. This is *essential* because `shared_ptr` does *not provide strong thread safety*. The latter is required to safely read a shared pointer instance that could be modified asynchronously.

The problem behind the scenes is that *after `shared_ptr` read the pointer* of `config_` and *before it incremented the reference counter* `config_` might *just being assigned* with a new object. In this case the assignment operator *decrements the reference counter*, and if it returns to 0 (because no reference except for `config_` points to the old object) it discards the old object. Unfortunately your thread has *read the old object pointer* and tries to increment the counter of the object that is currently destroyed. This is UB.

The lock together with the copy *prevents from this scenario*, because at the time the lock is released the reference counter of the object behind `config_` is *at least 2*. One for your copy and one for `config_` itself. So the object cannot be destroyed by an assignment to `config_`.