# Better way in C++ to keep a big plain struct atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, producer-consumer, compare-and-swap

I have a big plain struct without any methods. It includes many fields and another container(std::vector).
I need to make it atomic, so as to let one producer thread and many consumer threads can access it concurrently.
consumers don't modify the data, they just read the data. there is only one producer that adds/modifys(don't remove) the data, so it must keep the integrity/consistency of the data that can be seen by consumers whenever.

I think that there are two solutions can resolve it, but I don't know which one is better.

Method 1:

```
struct Single_t {
   size_t idx;
   double val;
}
using Details_t = std::vector<Single_t>;

struct BigStruct_1 {
   std::string      id;
   size_t           count;
   Details_t        details;
   std::atomic_bool data_ok { false };
};
std::map<std::string, BigStruct_1> all_structs1;
```

Method 2:

```
// Single_t and Details_t are same as the ones in Method1.
struct BigStruct_2 {
   std::string id;
   size_t      count;
   Details_t   details;
};
std::map<std::string, std::atomic<BigStruct_2> > all_structs2;
```

I prefer Methods2 up to now because **I don't need to check whether data_ok in everywhere of consumer's codes**. Infact consumer holds a pointer to a single BigStructs_2, I want the data can be accessed anytime(the data will not be removed).
Fortunately **there is only one producer in my system, so the producer can simply overwrite the data in one step: `std::atomic<BigStruct_2>::store( tmp_pod );`**, So I don't need to check whether or not the data is ready/OK(It should be always OK) when a consumer is reading the data, and I also don't need to use std::atomic::compare_exchange_xxx in this case, so it isn't necessary to offer a comparing algorithm between two BigStruct_2 objs. Am I right?

If I use Method1, when I need to modify the data I have to code as following:

```
auto& one_struct = all_structs1["some_id"];
one_struct.data_ok.store( false, memory_order_release );
// change the data....
one_struct.data_ok.store( true, memory_order_release );
```

**and check if data_ok everywhere in consumer's codes...** it's ugly and dangerous(easy to forget to check).

Any recomments/hints will be appreciated!

Comment: As an initial matter, neither `BigPOD_0` nor `BigPOD_1` are POD structs, as they contain a member of non-POD types `std::string` and `Details_t`

Comment: Setting `BigPOD_X` aside for the moment, it's not clear how you plan to prevent data races on `all_pods0` / `all_pods1`. Those are shared data structures that don't appear to be protected from concurrent access in any way. It would help if you prepare a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's my mistake, I will recorrect it.   I write POD here as what I actually emphasize is that this struct has no methods, i.e. it is just only a plain struct to be used to deliver data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make your `BigStructs` effectively immutable, and store them like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BigStruct_2> > all_structs2;
```

In order to make an update, the writer-thread would allocate a new `BigStruct_2` (using `std::make_shared` or whatever), set it equal to the object it wants to modify, then modify the new `BigStruct_2`, then insert the new `shared_ptr<BigStruct_2>` into the `map`.

Then whenever a reader-thread wants to read a `BigStruct_2` it can do so safely by holding a local `std::shared_ptr<BigStruct_2>` that it retrieved from the `std::map`.  Since your writer-thread is careful to never modify a `BigStruct_2` that it has already inserted it into the `map`, there is no chance that a reader-thread will be wrong-footed by a `BigStruct_2`'s contents changing while it is in the process of reading it.

Note that none of the above makes accesses to the `std::map` itself thread-safe, so you'd still need to synchronize all of those with a mutex.  Those actions should be quite fast, though, so I doubt that will be a problem.

Comment: I have processed the race condition of the map self, by adding a mutex.  For simplicity, I omitted it.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for updating shared objects that are predominately read is [seqlock](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-68.pdf):

> Seqlocks are an important synchronization mechanism and represent a significant improvement over conventional reader-writer locks in some contexts. They avoid the need to update a synchronization variable during a reader critical section, and hence improve performance by avoiding cache coherence misses on the lock object itself.

Comment: Thanks for your recomment!  The SeqLock is a new element to me, I have picked it into my tool box! But in this case, I think it is not very proper. If a SeqLock is used for sync the operations to the std::map, and a reader thread always can execute into std::map::find() after it get a sequence number instead of being blocked when a writer thread is writing/re-balancing the tree of the std::map, then it may be crashed because of dirty data. If SeqLock is for protecting the consistency of BigStruct, then I have to put the checking codes everywhere in the consumer. Thank you anyway!!!

Comment: @Leon Obviously, seqlock is useless for non-trivial data structures that can be transiently in inconsistent state while being updated and hence cannot be read concurrently during that time.

Answer (score 1):

`std::atomic<BigStruct_2>` will effectively be using lock: `is_always_lock_free` and `is_lock_free` are very likely to be `false` on aly implementation.

Also, you cannot use non-trivially-copyable type in `std::atomic` anyway (i.e. no `std::string` in your struct).

Generally, the ability of `std::atomic` to work with types of any size is for portability (in case if HW does not support atomics of particular size, but some does). It is not meant to be used in never-lock-free case.

The approach with `data_ok` is effectively lock-based either. You'll need to retry when `data_ok` is false.

You'd better just use `std::mutex` to guard data, or, if reads are prevalent, use `std::shared_mutex` to allow concurrent reads.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to absolutely minimise the lock time, I would suggest a third approach - you have a map of items which are structs holding an atomic pointer to the current values, as opposed to a map of shared pointers.

The advantage of doing this is that you don't have to lock the map to update values; you only need to lock the map for additions and removals.

Locking the map is effectively a *domain lock* which would block all threads, when most of the time you only really need to block any thread reading the map entry under interest.

You effectively perform "copy-on-write" with the data to modify it.  So you have

```
struct Single_t {
   size_t idx;
   double val;
}
using Details_t = std::vector<Single_t>;

struct BigStruct_Container {
   std::string      id;       //maybe put this in the digest if immutable?
   size_t           count;
   Details_t        details;
};

struct BigStruct_Digest {
   std::atomic<BigStruct_Container*> current_value;
};
std::map<std::string, BigStruct_Digest> all_digests;
```

With this, to perform an update you take a copy of the data and generate a new container.  Then you simply update the container pointer (digest) that's in the map.  Since you're not changing the value in the map, the map remains constant so there is no need to lock the map when updating.

---

A word of warning with using shared-ptrs; you need to use a mutex to protect the reference counting mechanism within since it is not thread-safe.  If you're using domain locks that should be OK, but it's not an optimal solution.

---

Note that given the map doesn't contain much data, you could even perform copy-on-write with the map, and have an atomic-ptr to the map itself.....

---

This is along the lines of "lock individual members, not the collection" in the book "Seven Concurrency Models in Seven Weeks" - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Seven-Concurrency-Models-Weeks-Programmers/dp/1937785653

Comment: The reference-counters used by `shared_ptr` use `std::atomic` functionallity and are therefore thread-safe without requiring a mutex (although of course the data the shared_ptr points to is not made thread-safe simply because a shared_ptr points to it).

Comment: Nope - I've fallen victim to this myself.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117985/1607937

Comment: They have fixed this in C++20 with `atomic_shared_ptr` I believe

Comment: I think @WhizTim's comment at your link contains the critical distinction; i.e. it's not safe to have two threads accessing the same `shared_ptr` simultaneously, but it is safe to have two `shared_ptr`'s, each accessed by a different thread, both simultaneously referencing the same object.