# Does C++ offer a thread-safe reference counter?

Tags: c++, reference-counting

Is there a thread-safe reference counter class in the standard C++ library, (or as an extension in Visual Studio), or would I need to write this kind of object from scratch?

I'm hoping for an object that purely performs reference counting as `shared_ptr` might, with the exception that it does so across multiple threads accurately, and without managing anything.  `shared_ptr` and it's cousin structures are nice because they define all the copy constructors and assignment operators you'd need, which ... are the most error prone part of C++ to me;  C++ Constructors are to C++ what the Kick-off is to American Football.

```cpp
struct Fun {

    // this member behaves in a way I appreciate, save for 2 short-comings:
    // - needless allocation event (minor)
    // - ref counting is only estimate if shared across threads (major)
    std::shared_ptr<int> smartPtr {new int};  

    // this is the hypothetical object that I'm searching for
    // + allocates only a control block for the ref count
    // + refCount.unique() respects reality when refs exist across many threads
    //   I can always count on this being the last reference
    std::object_of_desire refCount;

    // no explicit copy constructors or assignment operators necessary
    // + both members of this class provide this paperwork for me, 
    //   so I can careless toss this Fun object around and it'll move
    //   as one would expect, making only shallow copies/moves and ref counting
    Fun(); 

    ~Fun(){
        if(refCount.unique()){
             smart_assert("I swear refCount truly is unique, on pain of death");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your problem. Why do you not want to use a shared_ptr?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::shared\_ptr thread safety explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127816/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety-explained)

Comment: what's the purpose of `refCount.unique()` being thread safe if you can't lock it to stay at that value? It could increase between you calling unique and calling `smart_assert`

Comment: `shared_ptr` does thread-safe reference counting, and it can manage nothing if you set it up for managing nothing. So there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @PeterT - How would that be possible?  If unique() is true, shouldn't I be able to assume I hold the only reference in existence?  Who else could make a copy if I hold the only one left?

Comment: @AnneQuinn What's stopping another thread from copying that last reference just after you called `unique`?

Comment: @AnneQuinn New instances can be created by a weak ptr.

Comment: @super - oh, I think I understand now, we're talking about two threads with access to the refCount object itself?  So while only one exists, two parties are executing on it.  (as for weak_ptr creating copies... that's uh... why can a weak pointer even do that lmao)

Comment: Someone can be holding a `shared_ptr<...> &`, and copy from that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings about thread safety w.r.t. `std::shared_ptr` are

- If you have multiple threads that can access the same *pointer* object, then you can have a data race if one of those threads modifies the *pointer*. If each thread has it's own instance, pointing to the same shared state, there are no data races on the shared state.
- The final modification of the pointed-to object on a thread does not [*inter-thread happens before*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) another thread observing a `use_count` of 1. If nothing is modifying the pointed-to object, there are no data races on the pointed-to object.

Here's your desired type

```
class ref_count {
public:
    bool unique() const { return ptr.use_count() == 1; }
private:
    struct empty {};
    std::shared_ptr<empty> ptr = std::make_shared<empty>();
};
```

Comment: [`use_count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) is not necessarily accurate

Comment: @M.M there is a total order on accesses to the shared state, and we don't expose the pointer or the shared object, so the caveats don't apply

Comment: I agree that this is safe given the caveats mentioned on cppref. IMO, would be useful to elaborate on them in the answer briefly.