# Why is the counter in std::shared_ptr atomic?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

The implementation of `_Sp_counted_base` uses atomic counters:

```
_Atomic_word  _M_use_count;     // #shared
_Atomic_word  _M_weak_count;    // #weak + (#shared != 0)
```

Why are the counters atomic but the pointer not? Is atomic-count necessary? Are there any examples of its necessity?

(Because `std::shared_ptr` is not thread-safe, so I consider atomic-count is not necessary.)

Comment: @MarekR misleading comment removed

Answer (score 7):

> *Because `std::shared_ptr` is not thread-safe, so I consider atomic-count is not necessary.*

Your premise is invalid because `std::shared_ptr` *is* thread-safe (to an extent). And that's why the reference counters are atomic. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> To satisfy thread safety requirements, the reference counters are
> typically incremented using an equivalent of `std::atomic::fetch_add`
> with `std::memory_order_relaxed` (decrementing requires stronger
> ordering to safely destroy the control block).

Further reading: [std::shared_ptr thread safety explained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9127816/10871073)

Comment: Thanks,  the comment-"thread-safe(to an extent)" seems explains my confusssion. Atomic counters can protect ptr in some cases but not all cases.

Comment: @BBing the *control block* is thread safe. neither the pointers nor the pointed-to object are thread safe

Comment: @BBing is is the same exact thread safety guarantee that the entire C++ standard library has; accessing *different objects* of any standard library type are not a data race.

Comment: @Cubbi But, for `shared_ptr`, multiple threads accessing the (same) reference count(s) won't cause (for example) double deletion. That's why those counters *need* to be atomic.

Comment: @AdrianMole right, I'm just saying shared_ptr is not special:  res.on.data.races applies to all stdlib types (it's just most types don't need to synchronize anything as they don't share state between different objects of the same type)

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about thread safety is false. `std::shared_ptr` supports atomic operations since C++11 (the standard in which it was added). [See the documentation.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: Yes, but we'd need an atomic refcounter even without those.

Answer (score 0):

The access to the data of the object pointed to by the `shared_ptr` is not automatically thread safe, although the programmer can make it thread safe by synchronising all access via a mutex.

The reference count of `shared_ptr`s to the shared object is, however sharable across threads. Without this if on thread releases a reference and another thread makes a reference, there is a risk of accessing a deleted object.